# Actionscript without display list (update/draw loop)

Tags: actionscript-3, displaylist, game-loop

I've been working with several different programming languages recently, and I've come to the conclusion that I don't really like the display list in Actionscript. I would much rather have an update/draw loop and draw and manage everything manually like in XNA (C#).
What I do like in actionscript is the ease of use of events, movieclips animations and vector graphics.

What are the possibillites for this?
I would really like to be able to use animated movieclips, but I think that would be impossible without the display list, so I could settle with writing my own animation system with spritesheets.
Rewriting the entire event system isn't something I look forward to though.
Are there any (molehill) frameworks that work without the display list?

Comment: If you construct your system with abstraction in mind, you won't even notice you are using display lists. So why bother? ;)

Comment: You can abstract away the display list if you want, but you can't make your own game loop, because that would quickly exceed the 15-second script timeout limit (and Flash would never have the opportunity to redraw anything). Also, there's no way to sleep, so your loop would always run as fast as it can, sucking up 100% of one CPU core even if nothing interesting was happening.

Comment: Yea I'm not really looking into creating my own loop, just using an enter frame event would be fine. I just don't want to use the display list, but hold every item in an array and update/draw them manually myself. I'm not not really sure what you mean with abstraction though.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something similar by creating a Bitmap with the same size as the stage, attaching it to the stage as a child and using it like a "screen", by blitting your graphics on it every frame (on ENTER_FRAME event). I think it's even mentioned somewhere in the official Adobe documentation, as a method of efficiently animating a large number of objects.

Comment: Yes I have seen this aswell, but using blitting disables the use of movieclips or event listeners I think :(

Comment: @omgnoseat nothing prevents you from registering event listeners on the Bitmap. I've never used MovieClips with this, but I know for a fact that TextFields can be drawn on a Bitmap by creating a new Sprite, `sprite.addChild(textfield)` then `bitmap.bitmapData.draw(sprite)`. It should work for MC's, but I'm not sure it's worth it, performance/effort-wise.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise you to muster up the courage and let go of C# when programming in ActionScript. As Bjarne Stroustrup wisely said in his book *The C++ Programming Language*:

> ...applying techniques effective in one language to another typically
>   leads to awkward, poorly performing, and hard-to-maintain code. Such
>   code is also most frustrating to write because every line of code and
>   every compiler error message reminds the programmer that the language
>   used differs from 'the old language.' You can write in the style of
>   [another language], but doing so is neither pleasant nor economical in a language
>   with a different philosophy.

I think that applies very well to the question you're asking here.

Comment: I think that's very true, but I was hoping it could be achieved without moving too far from flash's core.